# MySQL ODBC, Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql

Hello everyone.

I am making small cpp application. My development condition is...

Windows 7
MySQL 5.7.10
MySQL ODBC 5.3 (unicode)

The problem is, when I execute SP in workbench It works properly so I can get a result set. 
But when my application execute same SP, It immediately shows error message on cmd window like this.

> [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.10-log]Lost connection to MySQL
>   server during query

I've set belows..

```
wait_timeout: 28800  
max_allowed_packet: 1048576  
skip_name_resolve: ON
```

Any Idea? Please help me!! Please!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on the query? Does it work with another query (some dead-simple stuff)?

Comment: @BurninLeo / SP is very simple. It just check parameter is valid and select the row of table that is very small. It's average processing time is 0.03 sec. I checked it with cache off.